# access data file name inside ctl file

Tags: shell, sql-loader

Using below script I am accessing my control file. I need to use file name passed in data i.e. $f and need to insert in TEMP_TABLE in control file. Kindly guide me regarding this matter.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd files_g41_in
e_payment_file=`ls *.DAT`
for f in $e_payment_file
do 
  sqlldr username/password@database control=/home/oracle/G41_GPRS/GPRS_G41.CTL data=$f log=/home/oracle/G41_GPRS/log_epmnt.txt 
done
```

GPRS_G41.CTL

```
LOAD DATA
APPEND
INTO TABLE TEMP_TABLE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "|"
(
    column1,
    column2,
    insert_date SYSDATE,
    created_by constant "ABC",
    FileName <- Here I need to insert filename passed as data 
 )
```